# Replacing the feature variables with encoded variables

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, data-cleaning, pandas

I have several nominal variables which I've encoded using the `LabelEncoder()` function. Now I want to replace the encoded values in the place of the raw datas of the features in the dataframe. I tried `df.replace()` but no luck. Below is the code snippet.

```
nominal_values = [
    'HouseStyle','ExterQual','BsmtQual','BsmtExposure','BsmtFinType1',
    'KitchenQual','GarageType','GarageFinish','GarageQual','GarageCond']
```

One of the column "KitchenQual" has values as follows:

{kitchenqual :['Ex','Gd','TA','Fa','Po']} representing "Excellent","Good","Typical/Average","Fair","Poor" respectively.

Another Feature "BsmtFinType1" has values as follows:

{BsmtFinType1: ['GLQ','ALQ','BLQ','Rec','LwQ','Unf','NA']} represeting

"Good Living Quarters","Average Liv. Quat.","Below Avg.Liv.Quat,","Avg. rec room", "Low Quality", "Unfinished","No Basement" respectively.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

lbe = LabelEncoder()
for noms in nominal_values:
    encode = lbe.fit_transform(cat_var[noms])
    cat_var.replace(to_replace=cat_var[noms],
                    value=pd.Series(encode),inplace=True)
```

I used `pd.Series(encode)` since the replace function will support only one of the following data structures

- Scalar
- dict
- Series

Comment: Hi. If you want help with code, you should post a minimal *working* example illustrating your problem in as few lines of code as possible, not just a snippet.

Comment: Hi @Miguel I have updated the question with the sample of feature values available for the same in the dataset. Please go through and guide me in where am I missing. Sorry for not giving out this information beforehand

Comment: What about `cat_var[noms] = encode` (or `cat_var[noms] = pd.Series(encode)` but I'm sure you just just use the list instead of casting as a `Series`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what is wrong with your code but this worked fine for me-

`cat_var.replace(to_replace=cat_var[noms].tolist(),value=encode,inplace=True)`

Instead of converting encoded values to series, convert series to list using `tolist()`.

Comment: Thank you so much @Ankit. It worked for me. But, Now there is a new issue.
The Label Encoder does the job by sorting the values of the features alphabetically. Ex: For "KitchenQual", the encoded values returned are as follows:

Ex:0; Fa:1; Gd:2; Po:3; TA:4
But, we can clearly say that the values we require are as follows:

Po: 0 OR 1; Fa: 1 OR 2; Gd: 2 OR 3; TA: 3 OR 4; Ex: 4 OR 5;

As of now, I've used the solution as follows:

cat_var.KitchenQual.replace(to_replace=sorted(list(set(cat_var['KitchenQual'].values)),reverse=True),value=[3,4,2,5],inplace=True)
Please help with a soln.

Comment: Due to the above-said issue, I am currently not able to use the Label encoder for encoding the nominal variables and I've used the mentioned code for all of the features and encoded manually

Comment: I dived deeper into this and found that at backend it basically uses `np.unique` to return the encoded values. [link] https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html
This function,(np.unique), by default, sorts the input array so in your example you will always get Ex:0, Fa:1 etc. The solution (you know) is to sort the list in reverse order.

Comment: But the Lable encoder fit and transform methods doesn't take any sorting value as a parameter. I tried finding out by anyway would it be possible to make the label encoder to use the custom sort, but in vain. I am still struggling to get a permanent solution for that.

Comment: You can have a look at this- http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/categorical-encoding/ordinal.html